# ScreenUpdating false until explicitly enabled again

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that calls a function after one second. To prevent flickering I want to disable `ScreenUpdating`. Unfortunately the property is reset to True after exiting `test`. Is there a way to disable the property until explicitly turned on again?

The code is roughly:

```
public sub test
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
App.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "EnableScreenUpdating"
end sub

public sub EnableScreenupdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```

Comment: As soon as the Macros finish execution the application resumes screen updating. If you need it to remain off, don't end execution. Call every function and sub within the same session instead of using `OnTime`.

Comment: Well, `onTime` is used in `beforeSave` to execute after the save event - so, if there is no alternative to mimick an after save event, Ill have to use `onTime`

Comment: In `BeforeSave`, do `Cancel = True`, do the save manually like `ThisDocument.SaveAs` and then without leaving execution you can immediately jump into `AfterSave`

Comment: As a comment on my comment, If you're doing `.SaveAs` inside the event, make sure to temporarily turn off events (`Application.EnableEvents = False`) otherwise you end up in a loop.

Comment: thanks i will try that. It seems thatll work.